# Lower bound of positive entropies of automorphisms on tori

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $A$ be an automorphism on tori $\mathbb{T}^d$. It is well known that the topological entropy
$$
h(A)=\sum_{\lambda} \max\{0, \log|\lambda| \}
$$ 
where $\lambda$ goes through all eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity.

Consider the case when $h(A)>0$. I would like to ask what are the lower bounds
$$
\inf_{A\in SL(d,\mathbb{Z}),h(A)>0} h(A)
$$ 
and
$$
\inf_{A\in SL(d,\mathbb{Z}),h(A)>0, d\ge 2} h(A).
$$
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $d$ the best known lower bound is due to Dobrowolski, who showed that if $h(A)>0$ then $$h(A) > \log\Big[1+\frac{1}{1200}\Bigl(\frac{\log\log d}{\log d}\Bigr)^3\Bigr].$$

For this and much more, see Chris Smyth's article *The Mahler measure of algebraic numbers: a survey*,  arXiv:math/0701397v2 [math.NT].

Answer (score 0):

We have $h(A)=\log\mathcal M(p)$, the Mahler measure of the characteristic polynomial of $M$, where $M$ is the matrix which specifies $A$. So if we assume [Lehmer's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_conjecture) (which remains unproven), then the answer is $\approx\log 1.17628$. (I presume you allow negative determinants, i.e., it's $GL(d,\mathbb Z)$ rather than $SL(d,\mathbb Z)$.)